# how to detect drag left to right with movement constrain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to detect direction of drag event on the static(no movement) element. 
From what I have searched, they use jquery-ui `draggable` that the element will move.

here is my try  ( I use `containment` to stop its movement but then I cannot detect direction of drag)

```js
var prevX = -1;

$('div').draggable({
  containment: "parent",
  drag: function(e) {
    //console.log(e.pageX);
    if (prevX == -1) {
      prevX = e.pageX;
      return false;
    }
    
    // dragged left
    if (prevX > e.pageX) {
      alert('dragged left');
    } else if (prevX < e.pageX) { // dragged right
      alert('dragged right');
    }
    
    prevX = e.pageX;
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.inside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `dragstart` for save start position X Y, end `dragend` for comparison